# Expectation of binomial distribution

Tags: expectation, binomial-distribution

Given that $X\sim B(20,0.14)$ calculate $P(X\leq E(x))$.

My attempt,

I found that $E(X)=2.8$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Use the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)!

Comment: $P(X \leq 2.8)=P(X \leq 2)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)$, since a binomial variable always takes on nonnegative integer values.

Answer (score 1):

This a hint, X takes integer values only, so $ X \leq 2.8 <==> X=0 $ or $ X=1 $ or $ X=2 $, so all you have to to do is to calculate $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)$

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified that $E\left[X\right] = np = 2.8$.
You are now interested in $P\left(X \leq 2.8\right)$, but since the Binomial distribution is supported for integer values only, we need only to consider the fact that:
$$P\left(X \leq 2.8\right) = P(X\leq 2) = P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2)$$